# errors in getting & sending Data (String ,Int ) in socket java

Tags: java, sockets, io

hi every one i have a project that get some`String` and `int`and from client and i want to send them to my server.but i have problem in getting this . i get nothing or wrong things. please help me.

Client:

```
//build a socket.
public void connectclient() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket("localhost", 9097);
    System.out.println("connect to server on port 9097");
}
public void startstreams() throws IOException , ClassNotFoundException      
{
in = socket.getInputStream();
out = socket.getOutputStream();
dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
dis = new DataInputStream(in);   
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
bwriter = new BufferedWriter (writer);
w = new PrintWriter(out, true);
}
public void writeSocketMyJson(String n) throws IOException
{
   w = new PrintWriter(out, true);
   w.println(n);
   w.flush();
   w.close();
}

massage1 = "username";
//send username that get from login form to server.
public void sendusername() throws IOException
{
  writeSocketMyJson(massage1);
}

massage2 ="admin";
//send password that get from login form to server.
public void sendpassword() throws IOException
{
  writeSocketMyJson(massage2);
}

//send access level to server.
public void sendaccess(int l) throws IOException 
{
    dos.writeInt(l);
    dos.flush();
}
sendaccess(21);
```

Server:

```
//build server.
public void connectserver() throws IOException
{
    listener = new ServerSocket(9097);
    System.out.println("Server is running on port 9097 ...");
}
//wait for new connection.
public void waitforclient() throws IOException
{
    socket = listener.accept();
System.out.println("A new client connected to the server");
}
public void startstreams() throws IOException
{
in = socket.getInputStream();
out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
dis = new DataInputStream(in);    
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
bwriter = new BufferedWriter (writer);
breader = new BufferedReader (reader);
}
public String readSocket() throws IOException
{
        breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while (true)
        {   
            massage = new String();
            massage = breader.readLine();
            if (massage.equals(null) == false) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return(massage);
}

//get username that client send it.
public String getusername() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{ 
    try  
    {
       username = new String();
       username = readSocket();
       System.out.println("the username is : " + username);
    }
    catch(IOException IOE)
    {
            IOE.printStackTrace();//if there is an error, print it out
    } 
    return(username);
}

//get password that client send it.
public String getpassword() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{ 
    try  
    {
        password = new String();
        password = readSocket();
        System.out.println("the password is : " + password);
    }
    catch(IOException IOE)
    {
            IOE.printStackTrace();//if there is an error, print it out
    }  
    return(password);
}

//get commend from client.
//admin or user send which commend 21-add new information 22-show information    
public int getaccess() throws IOException
{   
    System.out.println("server get access : " + dis.readInt());
    return(dis.readInt());
}
```

but when i call `getpassword()`i get nothing .
when i call`getaccess()`i get nothing.
why? please help me.
i have main class too that control the orders

main:

```
    //build Server & Client
    Server server = new Server();
    Client client = new Client();

    //Start Server & Client
    server.connectserver();
    client.connectclient();

    //Server wait for new connection
    server.waitforclient();

    //start the Streams
    server.startstreams();
    client.startstreams();

    client.sendusername();
    String msg1 =server.readSocket();

    client.sendpassword();
    String msg2 =server.readSocket();

    client.sendaccess();
    int n = getaccess();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is full of nonsense.  You do things like

```
breader = new BufferedReader (reader);

public String readSocket() throws IOException
{
    breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

and like

```
w = new PrintWriter(out, true);

public void writeSocketMyJson(String n) throws IOException
{
   w = new PrintWriter(out, true);
```

and like

```
    password = new String();
    password = readSocket();
```

I would suggest that you just throw it all away and begin from scratch, with some sample code for java sockets, of which there exist numerous on the interwebz.

The thing to remember is that you cannot just pretend that a socket is a regular stream, and you cannot just create a `BufferedReader` on top of it.  At any given moment you need to know exactly how many bytes were sent, and therefore exactly how many bytes to expect to receive.

So generally, on the sending side you cannot write a string and expect on the receiving side the end of the string to be detected with an end-of-line.  On the sending side you need to first write the length of the string, as a 32-bit int, so on the receiving side you know you are expecting exactly 4 bytes that contain the length of the string that follows.  Then, you can read the exact right number of bytes that make up the string.  Of course, do not forget that in java, a character is 2 bytes long.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have main class too that control their order that which kind of data i send it now and get it. 
Do you think  it is enough or not?